# Restrict memory allocation by Rhino javascript

Tags: java, memory, rhino

My java application needs to run users' javascript code. I need to protect application from scripts misbehavior (possibly, unintentional). I implemented API calls restriction and added time limit against possible endless loops. However I have not found protection against OutOfMemory error which may be caused by allocating too much objects, array elements etc. inside script.

Currently I have only two ideas:

- call application inside shell script and restore its state somehow if it failed with OOM;
- intercept Context#observeInstructionCount and frequently check that allocated memory amount did not grow too dangerously.

Both variants are very vague and stupid, so I would like something more smart.

Answer (score 1):

The only way this can be done is to run the javascript code in a separate process and set the `-Xmx` parameter for that JVM.